Confusion about notation in Fayyazuddin Riazuddin A Modern intro to Particle Physics
In section 5.1 of above mentioned book, the authors write an infintesimal unitary transformation as follows;
$$U(a) = 1 - \epsilon_i^j A_j^i + O(\epsilon^2)$$
Im quite confused by this notation, especially as my previous encounters with infinitesimal unitary transforms looked more like  $U(\alpha) = 1 + \alpha G$, where $\alpha$ is an infinitesimal parameter and $G$ the generator.
The authors state that $A_i^j$ is the group generator, but I am confused as to what the double indices are representing, and how they are contracting with $\epsilon_j^i$, which the authors are calling the parameter. So what exactly are $\epsilon$ and $A$, and what are the indices on them representing?

Don't have the book, but in general, a group has more than one dimension, i.e. multiple parameters. Now whether you call them $\alpha_i$ or have two indices instead (as is common in e.g. lorentz trafos) is kind of arbitrary. (For unitary group, I normally only see one). $A$ should be a "matrix" for EACH $ij$ though, for this to make sense.

The matrices A appear to be hermitean, while the matrix parameters ε appear to be antihermitean, to yield unitary $U=\exp (\operatorname{Tr}\epsilon A)$ s. Keep reading and check these statements.

It’s strange that the book doesn’t explain its notation.

It is a notation which has lost out, historically. The book takes special pain to send the reader to problem (5) of that chapter, to ensure the notation is fully and unconditionally understood.

@CosmasZachos ,Confuse-ray30 thanks im starting to understand now. Can you elaborate on how $\epsilon$ and $A$ are antihermitian and Hermitian?
